# Programmatically disable connectivity to a port on a remote machine

Tags: c#, wmi, ports, connectivity

I am trying to figure out the best way to disable/enable all the connections to a specific port on a remote machine.  My first thought was to modify the firewall rule for that port using WMI but after looking around for a little bit, it doesn't seem that WMI supports this. Anybody have any good suggestions on making this happen?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure if there's a way to change firewall settings remotely, to me that sounds sort of ironic. One option would be to host a process on the machine you want to change settings for, and then use an IPC mechanism (remoting or `WCF`) to connect to that host process from a client process and basically tell it to modify settings.

Comment: Not sure if I am allowed to install new processes into these remote machines. I can ask but I doubt I will be able to.  Is there any other solution you can think of? Keep in mind I don't have to do this through firewall but I thought that would be the easiest way.

Comment: If you have access to the machine you want to control ports on you can use the INetFwMgr found in the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common namespace to interact with the firewall.  That is if you have access to the remote machine, otherwise I am not sure there is a way to completely do it remotely.  Think about it would you want the ability if you had a server out there for someone to be able to open and close ports remotely?  Even if your access was locked down that would be a major security flaw in an OS imo.

Comment: Bearcat, Yes I do have access to the remote computers. I just don't think I'm allowed to install anything on it. I will try this method and let you know how it goes. Thanks